# Modified TFS Destination path

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am working with Team Foundation Server and I'm trying to fetch content from the server into my local folders.

so basically I'm using: tf get "companyName" /recursive /force /noprompt in the command prompt and everything is working smoothly and it gets stored under

C:\Users\myFolders\Escrow\XYZCompany\TFS

I'm using a program class and the path gets called from an app.config (XML) file into my visual studio class.

Is there a way to change the final path? I need to segregate the customers into subfolders so C:\Users\myFolders\Escrow\XYZCompany\TFS\CompanyOne or something similar, can this be done or altered? if I change the path I always get a message that everything is up to date and if I don't include the TFS folder, it gets created automatically whenever I run my command.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled by the workspaces you have mapped. A workspace represents the mapping between a location in source control and a folder on your PC.

It's not entirely clear whether your intent is to map the **same** source control location to **multiple** folders on your PC. You can't do that. In that case, it sounds like you need to adopt a branching strategy to allow for isolation of work between different customers.

Comment: basically I would like to segregate the destination. I have a different path for my workspace but since we're fetching for multiple customers, I was wondering if that was possible, to add more subfolders

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't map the same repository to the subfolders of one folder. You could either:

1. Create multiple workspaces. Each customer has a workspace and map to different path.
2. Use [branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-branches-isolate-risk-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts). In general, you should map your entire team project to a single local folder under for example `c:\Users\YourName\Source\Workspaces\`, If you create branches for each customer, then you could map branches to `c:\Users\YourName\Source\Workspaces\Main` or `c:\Users\YourName\Source\Workspaces\branch`